# Simple C++ program caught by Windows AppVerifier when it exits

Tags: c++, windows, application-verifier

My simple test code *dummy.cpp*

```
int main() 
{ 
   return 0; 
}
```

Windows AppVerifier(v4.0) always catches when the code exits. 
I don't know what is wrong.
My ApplicationVerifier configuration:
[image: configuration]

When dummy.exe exits:

[image: exception window]
[image: visual studio debug window]

**UPDATE**:
@VTT's comment was helpful. I updated Appliction Verifier to version 10.0 via 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to update app verifier to version 10.0 or newer.

Comment: @VTT Thank you! version 10.0 works.